# Set App Permissons on a New Site by Default

Tags: sharepoint-addin, app-permissions

Is it possible to have the Site App permissions set up automatically when creating a new site? Each time we create a new site and want to use a app step in a workflow we first have to setup the Site App permissions per [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-workflo). Is there a setting in Central Admin or a site feature to turn on so we don't have to got through the setup?

Comment: You can achieve using PowerShell script. If you using SharePoint on-primies then you can create site template & create new site using that site template

Comment: Thanks Bharat, but how can I trigger that PowerShell script. I don't want to do it manually. We are creating the new site automatically through this method: https://www.dmcinfo.com/latest-thinking/blog/id/8661/create-site-from-template-using-sharepoint-2013-workflow . So each time a site is created we need the App permissions set.